# Mac OS X - where to find Chrome and Firefox temporary files?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, temporary-files

In Ubuntu, both Chrome and Firefox store temporary files in `/tmp`. Now I'm using Mac OS X and I don't know where to find temporary files, such as flv videos. Do you know something about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox stores its files in `/Users/username/Library/Caches/Firefox/`.

Chrome stores its files in `/Users/username/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/` and (very short-term) in `/private/var/folders/`.

You can see these paths when you run either of the following:

```
sudo fs_usage -f pathname Google\ Chrome
sudo fs_usage -f pathname firefox-bin
```

---

If you just want to download FLV files off a video sharing site, I suggest using a browser plugin, or Safari's Web Inspector with resource tracking.

Answer (score 0):

If they follow the correct OS X conventions, the temporary files will be in

```
/var/folders/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
```

where the x's represent some sort of random string, which is per application (I think).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu for Firefox, you can do:

```
Tools > Page Info > Media
```

This will display the direct URL to any media file on the page. You can select/highlight it and click the Save As... button. Choose your directory and save it.

Works fine for me that way. I usually do it for .swf files but might work for .flv files as well.

I know this isn't a solution for the temporary file question but that this might help if you're trying to obtain a media file from a website.